# constraints between new UILabel with exist UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, interface, custom-controls, uilabel

I have a toolbar called Ntoolbar. It contain some UILabel, and have a method "insertTitle:(NSString) *title":

```
- (void) insertTitle:(NSString *)title{
   UILabel *newlabel = [ [UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.bounds.size.width / 2), 0.0, 150.0, 43.0) ];
   newlabel.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;
   newlabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   newlabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
   newlabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:(14.0)];
   [_ribbon_title addSubview:newlabel];

   newlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", title];
}
```

In ViewController, I have an outlet: 
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NToolBar *nToolBar;
And in ViewDidLoad(), I call this method to add an UILabel

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     [_nToolBar insertTitle:@"edit"];
}
```

Images:
Before adding new label: http://nt9.upanh.com/b2.s32.d2/9a3ff99d74de684dcc2075e98274a6e0_52281369.screenshot20130103at4.png

After adding new label, the old UILabel is covered by new UILabel?
http://nt5.upanh.com/b1.s33.d1/e6dd9ef7e8748dc445d71a5cc28a0d3c_52281635.screenshot20130103at4.png.

How can I add contrains between them?

Comment: seems the link to images is broken

Comment: please put new images...we cannot open the images